# Manipulation of color of an html image

Tags: css, png

So I thought I could do a smart manipulation of the color of a random shaped PNG image, by actually having 4 images of the same shape, but in Red, Green, Blue and Black, then set then on top of each other and manipulate their opacities.

I tried using the formula channelOpacity = channelVal / 255 / 3;

Well, it's not really that easy, it turns out. Has anyone attempted similar things and what would be a solution? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with (specifically) PNG

Comment: The problem was defnined starting from an attempt to manipulate a PNG's color. (@leonbloy)

Comment: PNG is a image encoding format. To start manipulating the pixel values, you (the browser) have already decoded it to a "raw" image, it does not matter if the original was PNG, JPEG, GIF or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea.  However, opacity alone doesn't seem to accomplish your objective, because the *order* in which the PNGs are defined will affect the color of their combination.

For example, if you have a red PNG, a green PNG, then a blue PNG, all with opacity 0.33, you'll get something like this:

[image]

If you rearrange their order as green, red, then blue, you'll get this:

[image]

Green, blue, then red will give you this:

[image]

There *may* be a way to take the order into account in your calculations, which could make your idea really useful.

Here's a snippet that sets the opacity of stacked red, green, and blue circles, based on the normalized rgb hex values from a color picker.  It does a decent job for colors that are *primarily* red, green, or blue, but it suffers from the issue I've described:

```js
var colorPicker= document.getElementById('colorPicker');

colorPicker.oninput= function() {
  var red  = document.getElementById('red');
  var green= document.getElementById('green');
  var blue = document.getElementById('blue');
  
  var r= parseInt(this.value.substr(1,2),16);
  var g= parseInt(this.value.substr(3,2),16);
  var b= parseInt(this.value.substr(5,2),16);
  var factor = 1/(r+g+b);
  
  red.style.opacity  = r * factor;
  green.style.opacity= g * factor;
  blue.style.opacity = b * factor;
}

colorPicker.oninput();
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Choose color: <input id="colorPicker" type="color" value="#ff0000">
<hr>

<img id="red"   src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Bullet-red.png/240px-Bullet-red.png">

<img id="green" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Bullet-green.png/240px-Bullet-green.png">

<img id="blue"  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Bullet-blue.png/240px-Bullet-blue.png">
```

Comment: Your take at "normalizing" was definitely better than what I came up with. I would have even used your suggestion if had I not found the solution I posted below.

Comment: The canvas is the perfect solution to the problem, but it was an interesting exercise to try this with opacity.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it through canvas, here: [permadi.com](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html)

Given that Firefox has also added support (v34) for the methods involved, this solution should work fine. Careful, there are a lot of mistakes in the code at the above link (I corrected them below), but the idea is awesome. Here's what it's about, roughly:

```
// image is an html image element
var myCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var myCanvasContext=myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var imgWidth=image.width;
var imgHeight=image.height;
// You'll get some string error if you fail to specify the dimensions
myCanvas.width= imgWidth;
myCanvas.height=imgHeight;
//  alert(imgWidth);
myCanvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);

// This function cannot be called if the image is not rom the same domain.
// You'll get security error if you do.
var imageData=myCanvasContext.getImageData(0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

// This loop gets every pixels on the image and
for (i=0; i<imageData.height; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<imageData.width; j++)
    {
        var index;
        index=(i*4)*imageData.width+(j*4);
        // then access your data and set it like this:
        // imageData.data[index+0]; // red
        // imageData.data[index+0]; // green
        // imageData.data[index+0]; // ... till alpha
    }
}
myCanvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0,0,0, imageData.width, imageData.height);

return myCanvas.toDataURL();
```